# .NET Maui: CollectionView GridItemsLayout Last Column Always Empty

Tags: xamarin, uwp, maui

How do I get my CollectionView to use the last column in the GridItemsLayout span?  No matter if I set the span as 2, 3, 4, the last column is always empty.

For instance, if the span is set to 3, this is what it looks like.
[image: sampleissue]

Here's my xaml:

```
<Frame Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10, 25, 25, 25" Padding="25">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView x:Name="listToolOptions"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Tools_Visible}"
                        Margin="0"
                        SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="3" VerticalItemSpacing="5" HorizontalItemSpacing="5" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame BorderColor="#f1f1f1">
                        <Frame.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame" Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Frame.Triggers>
                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ToolTapped"/>
                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" WidthRequest="15" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="{Binding Unselected}">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="FA" Glyph="&#xf0c8;" Color="{StaticResource Secondary}" Size="15"/>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>

                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" WidthRequest="15" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="{Binding Selected}">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="FA" Glyph="&#xf14a;" Color="{StaticResource Primary}" Size="15"/>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>


                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Part:" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="0, 0, 5, 0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />

                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="S/N:" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="0, 0, 5, 0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Serial}" />

                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="Mfg.:" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="0, 0, 5, 0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Manufacturer}" />

                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="Cal Due:" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="0, 0, 5, 0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Path=CalDueDate, StringFormat='{0:MM/dd/yyyy}'}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</Frame>
```

Is this a bug with UWP or am I doing something wrong that I'm just missing?